# Transformation of RV: Finding PDF

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, transformation

I am trying to work through this example problem in my textbook but I keep getting the wrong final answer.

**My Notation:**
PDF X : p<sub>X</sub>(x)
CDF X : F<sub>X</sub>(x)

**Question:**
Consider the transform Y=X<sup>2</sup>
if p<sub>X</sub>(x) = o.5e<sup>(-|x|)</sup>, find the PDF of Y.

**My Solution**

F<sub>Y</sub>(y) 
= P(Y$\le$y)
= P(X<sup>2</sup>$\le$y)
= P(X$\le\pm\sqrt y$)
= [P(X$\le\sqrt y$)+P(X$\le-\sqrt y$)]
= [F<sub>X</sub>($\sqrt y$)+ F<sub>X</sub>($-\sqrt y$)]

F<sub>X</sub>($\sqrt y$) = $\int_0^\sqrt y$ p<sub>X</sub>(x)dx = $\int_0^\sqrt y$ o.5e<sup>(-|x|)</sup> dx = 0.5 - o.5e<sup>(-$\sqrt y$)</sup>

F<sub>X</sub>($-\sqrt y$) = $\int_{-\sqrt y}^0 $p<sub>X</sub>(x)dx  = $\int_{-\sqrt y}^0 $ o.5e<sup>(-|x|)</sup>dx = o.5e<sup>(-$\sqrt y$)</sup> - 0.5

After this point I figured I would add F<sub>X</sub>($\sqrt y$) and F<sub>X</sub>($-\sqrt y$) to get F<sub>Y</sub>(y), then finally take the derivative of F<sub>Y</sub>(y) to get p<sub>Y</sub>(y)... but after adding the two value together I get F<sub>Y</sub>(y) = 0 hence p<sub>Y</sub>(y) = 0

However, the text book (without showing a complete solution) said p<sub>Y</sub>(y) = $\frac{exp(-\sqrt y)}{2\sqrt y}$
Could anyone explain how they got this answer? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The book also mentions that Y cannot be negative (Y>0). Im still not sure how that helps.

Comment: Be careful: $X^2 < y$  is equivalent to $-\sqrt{y} < X < \sqrt{y}$. So
$$F_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\sqrt{y}}^\sqrt{y} e^{-|x|}dx = \int_0^{\sqrt{y}}e^x dx.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}F_Y(y) 
&= P(Y\le y)\\
&= P(X^2\le y)\\
&= P(-\sqrt y \le X\le \sqrt y)\\
&= [P(X\le\sqrt y)-P(X\le-\sqrt y)]\\
&= [F_X(\sqrt y)- F_X(-\sqrt y)]\\
\end{align}

Differentiating, we get

\begin{align}f_Y(y) &= \frac{f_X(\sqrt{y})}{2\sqrt{y}}+\frac{f_X(-\sqrt{y})}{2\sqrt{y}}\\
&=\frac{f_X(\sqrt{y})}{2\sqrt{y}}+\frac{f_X(\sqrt{y})}{2\sqrt{y}}\\
&=\frac{f_X(\sqrt{y})}{\sqrt{y}}\\
&=\frac{\exp(-\sqrt{y})}{2\sqrt{y}}\end{align}